# Move Non-WordPress users table to WordPress database

Tags: database, users, user-meta

I'm new to Wordpress. I have a users table for my non-WordPress site. Now I want to move my site to WordPress but I have few doubts -

1. Usually, We can transfer tables by exporting as a CSV file and import to the new database but since WordPress stores users' info in two tables - "wp_users" and "wp_usermeta". So How can I import my users' table from non-WordPress to a WordPress database?
2. I used a different password encryption method in my old site and WordPress uses a different encryption method. So How to store passwords in the WordPress table? I can ask my users to reset their passwords but we have more than 100K users, that's why I'm looking for a direct solution via code.

Is there any plugin to solve any of my issues?

Comment: 1) What properties do you have in your source database? If you have any that you want to keep that aren't in wp_users then you'll can add rows to wp_usermeta for each extra property.

Comment: 2) You'll either need to a) extend WordPress to recognise and validate the old scheme permanently; b) or recognise the old scheme once then have WordPress write a new hash with its own scheme on the first successful login; c) do a mass password reset and send all of your users password reset emails, although that's possibly risky tripping some anti-spam protection by sending that many emails at once